# Turn '$(this)' jquery to javascript 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to reverse jquery '$(this)' into javascript 'this'?

How can this be done?

Comment: `$(this)[0]` or `$(this).get(0)`

Comment: Um, just use `this` to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is *set based*, and lets you access the elements of that set using either indexer notation (`[]`) or the [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) method.

So if you have a jQuery set:

```
var set = $(this);
```

...you can access its elements via `set[0]` through `set[set.length - 1]` and via `set.get(0)` through `set.get(set.length - 1)` (`get` also supports negative indexes for indexing from the end).

In the case of `$(this)`, of course, you don't need to use `$()` at all — just use `this` directly. This is true whenever you have a raw DOM reference, whether `this` or `event.target` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` or `$` is primarily just a wrapper function that returns a jQuery object. So removing the `$` is all you need to get the normal DOM element `this`.

```
this // DOM ELement
$(this) // jQuery object
this // Again just a DOM Element
```

You need not do anything more. `this` will always be the primitive DOM Element, it's because you're wrapping it, that it returns you a jQuery object.

jQuery offers `.get` which does the same too, but offers the convenience of getting a specific element if `this` is a collection.